# How to sort the forms in TYPO3 Form Manager?

Tags: forms, sorting, typo3, backend, typo3-9.x

When working with multiple forms it would be nice to sort them by "Form name" in the listview of the backend module "Forms". I can't recognize a system in the default sorting. They are not sorted by filedate, filename or Form name.

How can I influence the sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display ordering by modifying the TCA and add a control [`default_sortBy`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html#default-sortby)

As mentioned in the documentation:

> Do not confuse this property with `sortby`: `default_sortby` should be set only if there is no `sortby`. The `sortby` field (typically set to *`sorting`*) contains an integer for explicit sorting , the backend then shows “up” and “down” buttons to manage sorting of records relative to each other.

By using the `up` and `down` buttons integers will be written into the field marked for `sortby`!

Comment: The Form Manager is listing *.form.yaml files. Are those automatically written to the database, f.e. to sys_file_reference ? I could not find any TCA settings in /typo3/sysext/form related to the backend form listing. How can I find the TCE setting, that needs to be adjusted?